# What is the difference between the LifecycleService and the Service class?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have been reading the documentation on Android Developer page, but besides the fact that one extends from  Service and implements LifecycleOwner and the other extends ContextWrapper, I have not been able to understand when to use one or the other..
Do both of them serves the same purpose?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

LifecycleService has additional functionality, so it's preferred if you need that functionality.

A LifecycleOwner allows other classes to subscribe to its lifecycle state. For example, some component in your application could automatically tear itself down, free up native memory, unregister listeners, etc. by subscribing to the Service's destroyed lifecycle stage. Then your Service code wouldn't have to worry about it.

You also have access to `lifecycleScope` in a LifecycleService, and that can be used to start coroutines that will automatically be cancelled when the Service is stopped.

ViewModel and LiveData are designed around the use of lifecycles, so you could theoretically use them with a LifecycleService, but that would probably be counter-productive since they are intended for UI.

Comment: is it the best practice to use with MVVM? I want to hear your opinion

Comment: Regardless of design pattern, it's handy to have a lifecycle coroutine scope, but only if your service needs parallelism.

Comment: But normal service already have onDestroy method, we can free up resources there, how is it different?

Comment: @JazibKhan It allows other classes to subscribe to those lifecycle changes. You could have a class that automatically tears itself down when the service is destroyed instead of requiring you to manually call a method on it to destroy it in your service’s `onDestroy()`.